# Export individual furniture from SweetHome3D to .obj (to blender)

Tags: java, export, blender, sweethome3d

my problem is:
I am using SH3D to create a project http://www.sweethome3d.com/ and afterwards I want to import it to Blender (http://www.blender.org/) . The problem is that when I use SH3D code to export and then import to blender, I realize that: what is imported to blender is categorized as a mesh, so in order to move one piece of furniture I have to select all the meshes of the piece.

Do you have any idea, how I could change the code  in order to do that? The object writer of SH3D is given below. Note that OBJWriter class just writes a "g" line for each Java 3D shape whatever it comes from a part of a piece of furniture, a wall or a room.

http://sweethome3d.cvs.sf.net/viewvc/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/src/com/eteks/sweethome3d/j3d/OBJWriter.java?revision=1.26&view=markup#l360

Thanks in advance:)

Dimitra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found to that was to

1. Remove all the furniture
2. Export the home with its walls and textures
3. Remove the home
4. Import each furniture, one by one and save it an .obj file.

But to do that, there were many alternations in the source code of Sweethome3d. 
If anyone is interested, I would be glad to send you files that I have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The 'g' stands for group, the obj file format allows for multiple groups, in other words you could have something like;

```
g chair1 leg1
... vertices defining a leg ...
g chair1 leg2
... vertices defining a leg ...
g chair1 leg3
... vertices defining a leg ...
g chair1 leg4
... vertices defining a leg ...
g chair1 back
... vertices defining the back of the chair ...
g chair1 seat
... vertices defining a seat ...
```

I'm not completely sure about this but from what I can tell, despite the *appearance* of that being a hierarchy, it's not, i.e. leg1 is not a child of chair1.   So each such group name would have to be unique if you had multiple chairs.

Now, given that, you could change the code for sh3d to use multiple groups, one for each node.  *However* I don't know if the Blender code properly parses and uses the multiple groups, or if there's any way in the Blender UI to select based on these groups.

Another alternative would be to alter the .obj export code in sh3d to output multiple files and read each of the files into Blender.  Of course then you have the problem that the origin points for each .obj file would be off... i.e. if you rotated a chair, rather than rotating about an axis through the center of the chair, the axis would be somewhere else, so the chair would move in an arc around the scene.

Part of the problem here is that the .obj file format is an *object* format, not a *scene* format.